# How do you determine what to put in .rhosts file in an VAX open vms when accessing from CYGWIN

Tags: cygwin, remoting, unix, vax

How do you determine what to put in .rhosts file in an VAX openvms system when trying to remotely access the server using a remote shell from Cygwin on windows XP ? .rlogin and rsh are the only methods that can be used to access the VAX server and it must be using Cygwin to remote in to the VAX server. SSH is not an option. When the VAX server is accessed from a Sun server it works fine. I have tried many combination's of possible things that Cygwin could be sending the VAX as far as a user name an address of origin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The asnswer to this question is that the client that tries to access the VAX has to have  the name of the VAX server (in this case ACSD5(but no user name is required)) in the .rhosts file of the client. I do not know why. The VAX must be trying to access the client in some way that requires that the .rhosts has the VAX server listed. So anyway problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

- What error message is being
  returned?
- Is there any output at
  all?
- If this is really a VAX (not an Alpha), is it using Digital's TCP/IP implementation or another vendor?